# iphone:How to stream and play youtube video with in application using MPMoviePlayer?

Tags: iphone

I want to make a youtube app like this (Youtube Stream) http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/youtube-stream/id384383425?mt=8# app for the iphone, where some videos are streamed/downloaded from a youtube and played within same app without launching iphone's youtube app..
I searched lot but couldn't find a clue on how to do it..can any one suggest a solution...

Comment: Mohan, I'm looking for the same code. Let me know if you find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to stream/play youtube video inside iphone app, but i don't know apple will recognize it or its under youttube  terms and condictions. Bellow i attach my .h and .m file plz check and say how it works..

**YoutubePlayerViewController.h**

```
#import<UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import<MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface YoutubePlayerViewController : UIViewController
{
    UITextField *yurl;  
    NSMutableData *responseData;
    NSString *cacheLink;
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *yurl;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *cacheLink;

-(IBAction)Play:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)removeKeyboard;
@end
```

[image]

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//YoutubePlayerViewController.m

```
#import "YoutubePlayerViewController.h"

@implementation YoutubePlayerViewController
@synthesize yurl,cacheLink;


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"view did load");
}


-(IBAction)removeKeyboard
{

    [yurl resignFirstResponder];

}

-(IBAction)Play:(id)sender
{

    //1.get the url
    NSString *url=yurl.text;
    //NSString *url=@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2o5MhaSWRs";
    //2.show loding view

    //3.make http request
    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];





    //3.parse jason string for itag=18
    //5.create an NSURL with that string
    //6.start the player with url

}



- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"did receving response");
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
    //NSLog(@"receving data");
    [responseData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    NSLog(@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    NSLog(@"%d",responseData.length);
    NSString* strServerResponse= [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",strServerResponse);
    NSLog(@"\n***********************************************\n");

    NSArray *temp=[strServerResponse componentsSeparatedByString:@"swfConfig"];
    strServerResponse=[temp objectAtIndex:1];

    temp=[strServerResponse componentsSeparatedByString:@".c.youtube.com,18|"];
    strServerResponse=[temp objectAtIndex:1];

    temp=[strServerResponse componentsSeparatedByString:@"||"];
    strServerResponse=[temp objectAtIndex:0];

    strServerResponse=[strServerResponse stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@",strServerResponse);
    self.cacheLink=strServerResponse;


    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"link" message:self.cacheLink delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.cacheLink];
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(5,150,310,230);  
    moviePlayer.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [moviePlayer play]; 

    [connection release];
}              


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: What about the legal issues of extracting hot links to mp4 - legal and apple store compliant?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy
Here is my example: https://github.com/comonitos/youtube_video

I used PSYouTubeExtractor.h class by Peter Steinberger It can get youtube mp4 video url and than downloading and viewing is not a problem

NSURLConnection + NSNotificationCenter + PSYouTubeExtractor + NSMutableData

Comment: i tried this method with iPhone and it worked fine.
but its not working with iPad .. the video plays and you can hear the sound of the video but the youtube player is not showing.

Comment: @comonitos ,@amit please help ..how to implemnt this classes ..cz code is not working on both simulator and device