# How to get frame size after autoresize is done

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, frame, cgrect

I wonder, how and when (viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear) can I get a UIViews frame size that was autoresized to fit its partent view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question why you want it but I imagine it is to layout your sub views. Luckily Apple knew you would want to do that and implemented `-(void)layoutSubViews` see this: [When is layoutSubviews called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728372/when-is-layoutsubviews-called)

Comment: I have (on the iPad) a webView that loads some local htmlcode to display a youtube video. the html div that holds the player needs to be the same size as the webView. but since my webview is autoresized I need to have access to its autoresized size. Yet all I get when logging the frame is the dimensions before resizing occurred.

Comment: What bothers me with that -(void)layoutSubViews method is that I would have to subclass a UIWebView which I'd like to avoid

Comment: Then you have a problem. Why not play the YouTube video directly so you get better control over the layout. This is a notoriously difficult problem to solve with hybrid apps. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459975/iphonehow-to-stream-and-play-youtube-video-with-in-application-using-mpmovieplay for how to do that.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what he wants with the question, and I still couldn't find an answer too

Comment: subclassing a UIWebView is not such a big issue. Especially if you only want to get access to the frame.

Comment: `layoutSubviews` gets called more than once so I can't use it to create a `CGContext` with the final `frame` :/

Comment: That's a different question... and you should ask it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `layoutSubviews`, but it gets called more than once which is a problem when I need the auto sized frame in order to create a `CGContext` to draw into.

The solution I used was to expose an `init` method on my custom `UIView` for its parent view controller to call in its `viewWillAppear`.

I wish there was a way to accomplish this all within the custom `UIView`'s implementation, but it eludes me (and Google and Apple's docs and SO).

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    CGFloat uIViewWidth = self.uIView.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat uIViewHeight = self.uIView.bounds.size.height;
    CGRect uIViewSize = CGRectMake(0, 0, uIViewWidth, uIViewHeight);
}
```

Answer (score -6):

```
    NSLog(@"%f; %f; %f; %f;", yourView.frame.origin.x, yourView.frame.origin.y, yourView.frame.size.width, yourView.frame.size.height);
```

this is how you can get frame of your view

Comment: Doesn't answer the difficult part: when.