# Download youtube video through gdata-objectivec-client

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am developing an iphone app in which i have to integrate the youtube api.
I am using gdata-objectivec-client library for iphone
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

I am able to search, like, dislike, upload video etc. through this library but i don't know how to stream and download the video from youtube using this library as there is no class for this.

My question is that is it possible to download/stream the youtube video through gdata-objectivec-client library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: simple answer .. No.. obviously why will youtube allow you to download videos ? . There might be other unethical ways to do it.

Comment: @GauravShah is exactly correct, Google wouldn't add a feature to their API to do something that goes against their own terms of service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant download youtube video using API. Its against thier Terms and conditions.

But streaming is possible i think.

Check this post
[iphone:How to stream and play youtube video with in application using MPMoviePlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459975/iphonehow-to-stream-and-play-youtube-video-with-in-application-using-mpmoviepla)