# Using YOUTUBE urls how to play video player in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to be able to click on a table view item and play the video. I'm trying to stream some YouTube videos using the `MPMoviePlayerController` but I'm having some problems. I am using json parser to retrieve the data from webserver. My problem is when a user clicks on a `UITableViewCell` is that the video player opens full screen and it just says "loading..." the entire time and the video does not load, no errors are reported either in the debugger.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad

{

urlsArray=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}

-(void)loadData

{

url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"urls”];

NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

NSError *jsonError = nil;

id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];

if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])      

{

}

else if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])

{

NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;

NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]init];

array=[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"video-urls"];        

dataDictionary=[array objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionary);    

}

[urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@“Key1”]]; 

[urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@“Key2”]]; 

[urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@“Key3”]];

[urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@“Key4”]];

[urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@“Key6”]];       

NSLog(@"%@",urlsArray); 

} 


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

selectedIndex=indexPath.row;

NSLog(@"%@ %d",urlsArray,selectedIndex);

NSString *currentUrlsArr=[urlsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSLog(@"urlstring %@",currentUrlsArr);

NSString *youTubeString=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="];

NSString *stringAppend=[youTubeString stringByAppendingString:currentUrlsArr];

stringAppend =[stringAppend stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSURL *urlString=[NSURL URLWithString:stringAppend];

NSLog(@"%@",urlString);

moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlString];

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;

[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;

[moviePlayer play];

}
```

Comment: This link may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459975/iphonehow-to-stream-and-play-youtube-video-with-in-application-using-mpmoviepla

Comment: Are you sure that the `urlsArray` contains data? I don't see you calling `loadData` anywhere.

Comment: I am calling loadData in viewDidLoad. I am calling like this - (void)viewDidLoad
{
   
   [self loadData];
    
    urlsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];}

Comment: This is my Actual code bro.......

Comment: Help me any body plz.i want to solve the issue.plz help me any body.....

Comment: The MPMoviePlayerController doesn't know how to extract video from HTML response, that you actualy will receive from (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...).

Comment: The best and more less legal way, to deal with youtube is play video inside the UIWebview! You can try the LBYouTubeExtractor but youtube team all the time changing the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You can play Youtube videos using [LBYoutubeURLExtractor] (https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView/blob/master/LBYouTubeView/LBYouTubeExtractor.h).

Download this class and use following code in your `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method:

```
LBYouTubeExtractor *extractor = [[LBYouTubeExtractor alloc] initWithURL: urlString quality:LBYouTubeVideoQualityLarge];
[extractor extractVideoURLWithCompletionBlock:^(NSURL *videoURL, NSError *error) {
        [appDelegate hideActivityIndicator];
        if(!error) {
            MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
           [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
           moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
           [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
           moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
           [moviePlayer play];
       }
}];
```

Using this method the given `videoURL` can directly be played in `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Hope this helps.